# Caused by: HiveException: at least one column must be specified for the table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, azure-databricks

```
var count = spark.table(table).count
println(s"""${table}, %d lines""".format(count))
```

when i use databricks, i just select table count, it error!

error info:

```
AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: at least one column must be specified for the table
Caused by: HiveException: at least one column must be specified for the table
```

sometimes when i insert overwrite table , it also happen!

Comment: Could you please add your table sample schema for better understanding?

Comment: I think this should work `var count = spark.table("table_name").count
println(s"""${"table_name"}, %d lines""".format(count))`